# What's overriding my .vimrc tabstop size setting for CMake files?

Tags: vim, vimrc, cmake, syntax-highlighting, tabs

In my `~/.vim/vimrc`, I have:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

and when I edit a plain text file, that is respected. However, when I edit a CMake file - these both becomes 8. I tried looking for the cause of this change, but couldn't figure it out:

- Nothing in `/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/cmake.vim` seems to be related to tab stops, or to include another vim file.
- Same for `/usr/share/vim/vim90/syntax/cmake.vim`.
- The `CMakeLists.txt` files I'm editing have no modeline.

What's causing this? Is there a definition I've missed? And - can I override it somehow?

Comment: `ftplugin/cmake.vim` would more likely contain such a setting than `syntax/cmake.vim`, but the version on my machine doesn't seem to alter those settings either.  Are you sure the file you're editing doesn't have a [modeline](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline)?

Comment: @jwodder: Nothing relevant there either... also, the file has no modeline.

Comment: What does `:verbose set tabstop?` show?

Comment: @muru: Ah-ha! `Last set from ~/.vim/pack/tpope/start/sleuth/plugin/sleuth.vim` ... shall you write the answer or shall I?

Answer (score 2):

To see in which startup files an option was set, use `:verbose set <option>?`. From [`:help :verbose-cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Averbose-cmd):

> When 'verbose' is non-zero, listing the value of a Vim option or a key map or
> an abbreviation or a user-defined function or a command or a highlight group
> or an autocommand will also display where it was last defined.  If it was
> defined manually then there will be no "Last set" message.  When it was
> defined while executing a function, user command or autocommand, the script in
> which it was defined is reported.